# Android jni .so библиотеки

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

Появилась необходимость использовать нативную библиотеку `proj4`.

1. Взял .so файлы из проекта https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps/tree/master/libs
2. Добавил их в `jniLibs`.
3. Взял из этого же проекта файлы привязки jni. [RtkGps/jni/proj-4.8.0/jniwrap/org/proj4/](https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps/tree/master/jni/proj-4.8.0/jniwrap/org/proj4)

В файле [PJ.java](https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps/blob/master/jni/proj-4.8.0/jniwrap/org/proj4/PJ.java) все JNI методы подчеркиваются красным с ошибкой: `"Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function"`

Проект собирается, но при запуске кода `new Test().runTest();` падает со следующей ошибкой:

```
08-23 18:54:46.941  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.tserv.ntripclient/lib/libproj.so 0x405215e0
08-23 18:54:46.942  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/data/com.tserv.ntripclient/lib/libproj.so 0x405215e0
08-23 18:54:46.943  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient I/TServ﹕ Test runTest
08-23 18:54:46.944  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.tserv.ntripclient/lib/libproj.so 0x405215e0
08-23 18:54:46.944  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/data/com.tserv.ntripclient/lib/libproj.so' already loaded in same CL 0x405215e0
08-23 18:54:46.945  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient I/Proj4﹕ ERROR loading:epsg
08-23 18:54:46.946  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-23 18:54:46.946  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020648)
08-23 18:54:46.953  11220-11220/com.tserv.ntripclient E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: +init=epsg:32632
            at org.proj4.PJ.<init>(PJ.java:85)
            at com.tserv.ntripclient.Test.runTest(Test.java:17)
            at com.tserv.ntripclient.ActivityMaine.onContextItemSelected(ActivityMaine.java:440)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2250)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2969)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:174)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:886)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:168)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
            at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3559)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1851)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3850)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 18:54:46.963      179-185/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.tserv.ntripclient/.ActivityMaine
```

`System.loadLibrary("proj");` нормально срабатывает

При создании .apk все .so в него пакуются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: proj4, насколько я помню, под java есть, его не обязательно нативным использовать

Comment: да есть proj4j java реализация, но там все печально очень, приходится с нативным бороться ... эх проект у меня хороший, перспективный, но опыта   маловато

Comment: Трейс или какие-то сообщения об ошибках должны быть в logcat, без них непонятно.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что здесь может быть корень проблемы    
`I/Proj4﹕ ERROR loading:epsg`